# Changed Tables+Jquery+forms+Postgresql

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, postgresql

I 'm very new in web developing and I need your help!
I need get something like html-table. it will a list of any records from Postgresql table. 
Then I want change each table's line via inputs of any form. Is there a ready examples or finished application? I found any JQuery based applications like JFormer, Zebra_Form but I haven't found how to it use?

Answer (score 1):

Use Google... There a many examples for people just starting in web development.

Just to start you off, you will need stuff like:

- A way to connect to the database e.g  `$connect =
  mysql_connect("localhost","root", "root");`
- A while loop e.g.  `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) { }`

Table simple as

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Title</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Data here</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thats pretty much all you need to do what your asking. That should give you some things to look at and maybe get you started.

Comment: I thing You understood me wrong. I meant I want find any free box version i.e JFormer, Zebra_form on Jquery or something like that. i'm familiar with elements.

Comment: I found an example used datatables jquery plugin like here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MiakZ_sbgM
Now I need to add the function which would be able to add new row to table via any form